# Schedule a local notification on firing a local notification

Tags: iphone, ios4, alarm, uilocalnotification, localnotification

I want to schedule a local notification when my previous local notification gets fired.
It should get scheduled disregarding the user taps 'View' or 'Cancel'.I am not getting proper place(delegate method)to schedule a new notification.According to Apple docs,application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: can be used but it doesn't seems to be get called when application comes to foreground from background and application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification: gets called only on click of 'View' and not on close.How should I do this?Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You are correct about the local notifications. You should click `"view"` to get the `didReceiveLocalNotification:` triggered. If you click `"Cancel"`, you are not caring about the notificaiton. If you don't care, why should the iOS care? :-)

You are scheduling the notification. So, you know when it will be fired. Don't you? Then why wait for the first notification to be fired? Just schedule the second notification along with the first notification.

**A workaround:**

[Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/WhatAreRemoteNotif/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW9)
 says that only 64 local notifications are allowed per app. So, schedule the first 64 notifications initially. And when the app opens the next time, check `[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]`, and schedule the next (64 - scheduledLocalNotifications) notifications.

```
int scheduledNotifications = [UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];  
int n = 64 - scheduledNotifications;  
[self Schedule-next-n-notifications];
```

*Note: We can't guarantee that this will work perfectly. In case, if the app opens after very long gap, for example after 1 or 2 months, some notifications would have not been scheduled at the proper time.*

Comment: Yse Simon,your logic is correct but I have a database of 365 records in it and as docs says we can't schedule this many notifications at a time.So I thought it will be better to schedule it one by one

Comment: @Yogi, Those notifications will be fired in regular intervals or irregular intervals?

Comment: @Simon:irregular,otherwise repeating notifications was an option

Comment: @Yogi, Yes but we can't to use repeating notifications for every 2 hours, 2 days , 2 weeks, 2 months like that :-)

Comment: @Yes,But here they are not on regular intervals.How can we do this?I am trying this for a whole day

Comment: @Simon:Wow,looks great,will try and reply you:D

Comment: @EmptyStack:One query,If the scheduled notifications are more than 64,then they simply get discarded by the application.So how can we keep them on hold till scheduled notifications becomes lesser than 64 as the count of [UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] never exeeds 64?

Comment: @Yogi, You can not keep them on hold. You need to schedule the remaining notifications if the `scheduledLocalNotifications` becomes lesser than 64. You can check this condition on every time the app launches.

Comment: My app allows user to set his own notifications i.e. alarms also alongwith 365 predefined alarms.Can this strategy prove harmful to those alarms?Thanks for your support.....

Comment: @Yogi, As I've mentioned in my answer. This method doesn't guarantee that this will work perfect. To make it work as expected, the app should be opened at regular intervals. That also we cant guarantee because the user may not open the application at regular intervals. If you want a perfect solution, you should restrict your app to schedule the notifications with `repeatIntervals` available for UILocalNotifications.

Comment: Yes,you are right...at present I am cancelling the old notification in viewDidAppear and scheduling next one.Working ok if user interacts with the app regularly:)

Comment: @Yogi, Yeah. That is the least possible solution for this problem :-)